# How can I show webp Image in React Native iOS?

Tags: react-native, webp

Our Image and video in DB are compressed into webp. However, I'm an iOS developer using React Native. On React Native docs, iOS doesn't support webp image. How can I handle this? My RN version is 0.59. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

It’s the first dependency I install on every new RN project.

Comment: Does this work with react-native-webview if webp image is within webview?

Comment: as of 2022 react-native-fast-image is not maintained by its creator https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/685

Answer (score 3):

If you want something less intrusive: https://github.com/Aleksefo/react-native-webp-format

Doesn't need a separate import, you can just use it with standard Image/ImageBackground component like:

```
<Image source={require('../../assets/example.webp')} />
```

Comment: Does this work with react-native-webview if webp image is within webview?

Comment: No clue, haven't tried it with react-native-webview. I'd assume it will work or not based on browser.

Comment: I needed to show animated webp. This library working as expected for both ios and android. Thanks